# Convert PHP array to Json contain object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to create following json from php array using `json_encode()`:

```
{
"Image":"wordpress",
"Env" :[
    "VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com"
    ],
"ExposedPorts":{
    "8080":"80"
    }
}
```

I get stuck at the ExposedPorts , please help. This is my php array but it does not work :

```
[
     'Image'=> 'wordpress',
      'Env' => [
            "VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com"
               ],

     'ExposedPorts'=>json_encode(["8080"=>"80"],JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
]
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: where is your php array?where you got stuck?

Comment: what do you mean by "stuck" ? Can you explain a lil'bit ?

Comment: i dont know how to create json object in ExposedPorts from php array

Comment: @spqa  provide your php array please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you json_encode the whole array like this,

```
<?php
$array = array(
"Image" =>"wordpress",
"Env" =>
    ["VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com"
    ],
"ExposedPorts"=>
    array("8080"=>"80"));

    echo json_encode($array);
```

output:

```
{"Image":"wordpress","Env":["VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com"],"ExposedPorts":{"8080":"80"}}
```